# Embed Another Application inside tkinter window

Tags: python-3.x, windows, user-interface, tkinter

I want to embed an application to my Tkinter windows:
Here is my file tree:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
window=Tk()
window.geometry('1000x700')
app_1= open('./Applications/App_1.lnk')
app_1_img= open('./Images/App_Icons/App_1.png')
L1=Label(window, text=os.system(app_1))
L2=Label(window, img=app_1_img)
L1.pack()
L2.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Here is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\asmit\Desktop\App\Index.py", line 7, in <module>
    L1=Label(window, text=os.system(app_1))
TypeError: system() argument 1 must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

[image]
Here is what I want:
[image]
Thank You in advance

Comment: This is [not supported](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683).

Answer (score 0):

When you:

```
app_1 = open('./Applications/App_1.lnk')
```

The `app_1` name will point to a file object. Same for the image.

You'll have to read the file to get its contents. See [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Usually this is implemented as:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    contents = file.read()
```